# Error while uploading and edit properties of Document in DL in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I receive an Error Stating

> An unexpected error has occurred whenevr I try to Upload a Single Document or Edit Properties of the Document.

I have used Custom Master Page on this site.

Comment: Solved it, it was a Custom Field that which got corrupted due to which this occured. After deleting it. It worked fine.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and mark it as answer?